# CoreData deadlock with background thread

Tags: multithreading, core-data

I am using the classic multiple MOCs sharing the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator as I understand it performs better than the parent/child contexts according to this:
http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout

I am being very careful about creating the contexts and using them on the thread/queue that creates them.

The deadlock is this:

Main thread is executing a fetch request and hung on a mutex in [NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]

```
#0 0x3ad840fc in __psynch_mutexwait ()
#1 0x3accd128 in pthread_mutex_lock ()
#2 0x328eee90 in -[_PFLock lock] ()
#3 0x328ff350 in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] ()
#4 0x328fdf16 in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
```

Background thread is hung on a lock I put on the persistent store coordinator prior to calling [coordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:objector].

```
#0 0x3ad840fc in __psynch_mutexwait ()
#1 0x3accd128 in pthread_mutex_lock ()
#2 0x328eee90 in -[_PFLock lock] ()
#3 0x00093180 in -[DataManager getObjectByUri:context:]
```

I understand that this is difficult to debug from a post but any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  BTW...this happens rarely.

Comment: Could you still provide some code?

Comment: Alexei - I decided to change over to use parent/child contexts to see if that helps my problem.  Will let you know whether I see the deadlock again.  Thanks for your help.